# Are there any potential issues when working with older versions of ROS on the following robotic setup?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am working on a project, and the robot that I have access to is similar to a turtlebot based off an iRobot. It has a Kinect as well, ofcourse. The issue is that this particular robot was developed on a system with the following specs -

- 2x Intel Atom CPU N270, 1.60 GHz, 2GB
- Ubuntu 11.10
- ROS 1.6.8

Since this system is a "research robot", I don't wish to update it in case I mess it all up and end up losing the work that was done on it.

What are the potential problems that I might face in this case -

- Do I need to update it in order to be
  able to work with Kinect properly
  (considering I won't get much support
  for the old ROS)?
- Will implementing any motion planning
  algorithm (utilizing real-time info
  from the kinect) on this system lead
  to performance issues?

I understand this isn't a typical ROS related issue, but it would be helpful if anyone could point out any issues and/or solutions for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84831/are-there-any-potential-issues-when-working-with-older-versions-of-ros-on-the-following-robotic-setup?/) by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 237 on 2013-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The older openni drivers had problems -- however, they also had stable points. Being on an older Ubuntu release with an older ROS install, you might hit one of those stable points. I think you'll just have to test it and see.

That Atom is not all that powerful, depending on what you are doing, you may want to turn down the Kinect frame rate or image size (see the openni_camera driver docs) to help out your code. Regardless, the question above is far too broad -- you can certainly find *some* motion planning algorithm for which you cannot run it on that Atom, and you can certainly find several motion planning algorithms for which the Atom is overkill -- it really all depends on what you are doing and at what framerate/image size.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-09-29**:
Thank you! I will look into it further then.

**Comment by [nemesis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4134/nemesis/) on 2013-10-03**:
@fergs - I was provided with a replacement laptop. The replacement seems to be worse than the above configuration.

Intel Pentium M, 1.70 GHz, 1 GB RAM

I guess this won't do either?